# reset() function called on fine uploader object is not working

Tags: file-upload, fine-uploader

I wonder what is the proper way to reset FineUploaders uploader to its initial state?

```
$('#uploader').fineUploader('reset')
```

This results in "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'reset' of undefined " in definition of reset function

```
reset: function() {
    this.log("Resetting uploader...");
    this._handler.reset();
    this._filesInProgress = [];
    this._storedIds = [];
    this._autoRetries = [];
    this._retryTimeouts = [];
    this._preventRetries = [];
    this._button.reset();
    this._paramsStore.reset();
    this._endpointStore.reset();
--> this._pasteHandler.reset(); <--
    this._netFilesUploadedOrQueued = 0;
},
```

So it seems that _pasteHandler was not created. Am I missing something in my configuration or is this bug in the uploader itself (which I seriously doubt as I wasn't able to found anyone else with similar issue)

As this is my first encounter with Fine Uploader any advice will be highly appreciated .

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This DOES appear to be a bug in Fine Uploader 3.4 (released yesterday).  It will affect anyone attempting to reset the Fine Uploader instance without the paste to upload feature enabled.  Can you please open up a bug report in [the Github project's issue tracker](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues?labels=enhancement%2CP3&state=open) so it can be tracked?  I'll try to fix this today.

Update: Fixed in 3.4.1.

Comment: No need to open up a ticket.  I just opened one at https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/778 and should be pushing out a new version, 3.4.1, with the fix shortly.

Comment: Ah, thanks. But just for the record this probably wasn't introduced in 3.4 because at first I've came across this bug using 3.3 and then updated the version (in case that issue #759 was in fact affecting more then just IE).

Comment: The issue you have described is a regression caused by work on 3.4.  There was another, separate issue with reset in 3.3 - [#759](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/759). They are two separate issues that, unfortunately, caused problems with the reset function.  I've now pushed out 3.4.1 which should hopefully put an end  to the reset issues.  Thanks for reporting this.